# what encoding made these characters when accompanied with caron into something different

Tags: java, mysql, node.js, encoding, coffeescript

There are some croatian strings that has [caron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) with some of the characters in mysql db.

I call a API which is written using Node.js and which in turn it calls the Java based API and which in turn fetches the data from mysql db.

I'd like to find out what **encoding** in API layers made these(left) into something different(right).

- **Mreže** -> *Mre~e*
- **Zaštita** -> *Zaatita*
- **poslužiteljskim** -> *poslu~iteljskim*
- **omogućavaju** -> *omogucavaju*

I have tried googling but it didn't help.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What encoding does the MySQL DB use?

Comment: I don't know what encoding it does probably some iso encoding I guess

Answer (score 3):

The first three are created by someone being given UTF-16 and thinking "oh, I'll remove every other byte so that I can process it as ASCII".

```
>>> hex(ord(u'ž'))
'0x17e'
>>> hex(ord(u'~'))
'0x7e'
>>> hex(ord(u'š'))
'0x161'
>>> hex(ord(u'a'))
'0x61'
```

The fourth I have no explanation for, other than some unidecode operation.

```
>>> hex(ord(u'ć'))
'0x107'
```

Comment: Please explain me.He has set UTF-16 by default and he converted it to ASCII so ASCII is not able to interpret the caron.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It hasn't been "converted" so much as it has been "destroyed". '0x4d 0x00 0x72 0x00 0x65 0x00 0x7e 0x01 0x65 0x00' -> '0x4d 0x72 0x65 0x7e 0x65'

Comment: I am not able to understand..Can you get me step by step from the beginning to end.Thanks in advance !

Comment: "ž" is U+017E. When encoded as UTF-16LE it becomes 0x7e 0x01. When stripped of the second byte it becomes 0x7e. "~" is U+007E.

Comment: "š" is U+0161.When encoded as UTF-16LE it becomes 0x61 0x01.When stripped of the second byte it becomes 0x61.'a' ..Am i right ?

Comment: only for caron added characters we get two bytes...so removal of one byte doesn't seem a problem as its not obvious(all other character will have one byte) ? Kindly correct me If I am wrong

Comment: You *always* get two bytes when converting a character with a codepoint of FFFF or less to UTF-16. With ASCII characters that second byte is always 0x00. And since 0x00 is useless we strip it off. Or so you would think *if you had no idea what you were doing*. As you have discovered, removing that byte *does* change the text.

Comment: My doubt is the application is running for years.so all other english characters also possibly would have 0x00 ..so removing that would have changed text right ! how come no one was aware of that ..only when this caron is placed this problem has been discovered ? Actually I am trying to narrow down this problem..Hope you help me..
I am trying to ascertain this is the problem !
I really appreciate your help

Comment: Text in Latin-1 and UTF-16 is identical except for that 0x00 byte. If no one uses non-Latin-1 text then no one will notice the issue.